# get the datatable with distinct rows in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a datatable returned as a result of fetching data from a spreadsheet. I need to display the resultset only with the distinct rows depends up on only a column.

For example I have a datatable with columns

```
id | name | age | email
```

Then if more than one record with the same **id** is listed it should omitted. I tried

```
dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true)
```

but it returns the distinct records with respect to all columns. I need the distinct records only based on the id.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: what does this have to do with `linq`?

Comment: i had seen many answers similar to this. for eg:var myResult = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(c => (DataRow)c["email"]).Distinct().ToList(); but not working for me.

Comment: Use [distinct](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) in your sql operation

Comment: im getting the result from an excel sheet.

Comment: So why you wrote this: datatable returned as a result of **sql operation**??

Comment: sorry.y mistake.corrected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` :-

```
DataTable result = dt.AsEnumerable()
                     .GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("Id"))
                     .Select(x => x.First()).CopyToDataTable();
```

Please note, in case of a matching `Id`, I am taking the first record and ignoring the rest.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid - Because OP is expecting distinct records based on 1 columns not all.

Comment: Ah, yes good point, there's no filter on the Distinct method is there - apologies

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention the column name on which the ToTable operation will execute to select distinct values.

Please find below the code section

```
DataView view = new DataView(table);
DataTable distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "id");
```