# VB.NET Fill DataGridView from JSON

Tags: json, vb.net, solr

I am struggling to fill a DataGridView from a JSON that I get through a webrequest to SOLR.

JSON Example:

```
    {
  "response":{"numFound":6,"start":1,"docs":[
      {
        "PRODUCTNAME":"Office Chair",
        "CURRENCYCODE":"EUR",
        "CLIENTCODE":"Northwind Inc",
        "LANGUAGECODE":"ENG",
        "KEYWORDS":"spins, adjust, castors"}]
  }}
```

The below will work and get one token and put it in a label.

Code:

```
    Private Sub SOLR()

        Label2.Text = Nothing
        Try
            Dim fr As WebRequest
            Dim targetURI As New Uri("LinkToJson")

            fr = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(targetURI), WebRequest)
            fr.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("admin", "admin")
            If (fr.GetResponse().ContentLength > 2) Then

                Dim str As New StreamReader(fr.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
                Dim streamText As String = str.ReadToEnd()

                Dim myJObject = JObject.Parse(streamText)
                Label2.Text = myJObject.SelectToken("response.docs[0].KEYWORDS")
                Label3.Text = streamText

            End If

        Catch ex As WebException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
        End Try
    End Sub
```

I tried to deserialize it, but I get an error for the below:

```
Dim table As DataTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataTable)(streamText)
DataGridView1.DataSource = myJObject
```

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable. Expected StartArray, got StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the "**docs**" array to the `DeserializeObject` function in order to load the JSON data into `DataTable`.

```
Dim myJObject = JObject.Parse(streamText)
Dim arr = myJObject("response")("docs")
Dim table = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataTable)(arr.ToString())
```

Comment: If you don't mind I have a few more questions. How do I rename the Tokens so they have a nicer name in the table? Does this work if I the JSON has multiple results? I added a restriction to only show the first one.

Comment: About renaming: You can look at DataTable.Columns collection. There is a name for each column there and you can rename after you load. Multiple results -> yes, docs is an array, so the DataTable will load all the elements of this array.

Comment: Cool! And this is probably an SOLR question. When I remove the rows=1 restriction from the link, I get 6 results, some of those are the same (the difference is the tokens I am omitting from the query). How do I get only unique results?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27940180/get-the-datatable-with-distinct-rows-in-c-sharp